# TextFormField doesn't show errors on validation

Tags: flutter

How could I show error messages if found by validation in TextFormField?

I'm using Stepper class to handle users' registration, also when tried to implement basic validation with setState, No error messages are shown in current text field being validated

Here's my code:

```
...
class _RegisterState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  static TextEditingController _inputController = TextEditingController();
  static bool _validate = false;
  static String _errorMessage;
  static int _currentStep = 0;
  static List<Step> _steps = [
    Step(
      // Title of the Step
      title: Text("Phone Number"),
      subtitle:
          Text('We need your 11 digit phone number to verify your identity!'),
      content: TextFormField(
        controller: _inputController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
          labelText: '01XXXXXXXXX',
          errorText: _validate ? _errorMessage : null,
        ),
        maxLength: 11,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      ),
      state: _validate ? StepState.error : StepState.editing,
      isActive: true,
    ),
// Other steps ...
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
      title: 'Signup',
      body: Stepper(
        controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: onStepContinue,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                child: const Text('Continue'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: onStepCancel,
                child: const Text('Cancel'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        currentStep: _currentStep,
        type: StepperType.vertical,
        steps: _steps,
        // Actions
        onStepTapped: (step) {
          setState(() {
            _currentStep = step;
          });
        },
        onStepCancel: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_currentStep > 0) {
              _currentStep = _currentStep - 1;
            } else {
              App.router.pop(context);
            }
          });
        },
        onStepContinue: () => _validator(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _validator() {
    if (_currentStep == 0) {
      // Validate number
      if (_inputController.text.length != 11) {
        setState(() {
          _validate = true;
          _errorMessage = "Phone number must be 11 digits";
        });
      } else if (!_matchInt()) {
        setState(() {
          _validate = true;
          _errorMessage = "Phone number must be correct";
        });
      }
    }
  }

  _matchInt() {
    RegExp re = RegExp(
      r'(\d{11})',
      multiLine: false,
    );
    return re.hasMatch(_inputController.text);
  }

  void _continue(int currentStep) {
    setState(() {
      if (_currentStep < _steps.length - 1) {
        _currentStep = _currentStep + 1;
      } else {
        // TODO: Validate data and register a new user
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Pressing `Continue` button doesn't show any error!
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of creating `Step`'s outside of the build method it should be inside to your build method.

make sure about you are building your `TextField` widget inside a `StateFullWidget`

also you can check your text with `onChange`

```
                  TextField(
                    controller: textEditingController,
                    onChanged: (String string){
                      print(string);
                      print(_validate);
                      if (string.length < 3) {
                        setState(() {
                          _validate = true;
                        });
                      }else {
                        setState(() {
                          _validate = false;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter the number',
                        errorText: _validate ? 'here' : 'change'),
                  )
```

Comment: Hello, this works well, thanks... I just wonder how to change StepState after moving steps to build() ?

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you want to do ? _be more specific_

Comment: When a validation is passed, the current step should be marked as completed so I don't know how to control `state` property to change it from `StepState.editing` to `StepState.complete`.

Comment: these `Stepper` properties may help you `onStepContinue`, `onStepCancel`  

[Stepper](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html)
`onStepContinue: (){
                      if(_validate) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentStep++;
                        });
                      }
                    }`